# Setting turn variable before enabling the flag in Peterson's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, concurrency

In Peterson's algorithm for 2 processes we have an array A = {bool a, bool b} and a turn variable. In the algorithm, the booleans are set first then the turn variable is set to the other. If we modify the algorithm so the turn variable is set to itself instead of the other process, why wouldn't the algorithm work?

Answer (score 0):

That works in the contended case where both processes try to write the turn variable at the same time.

It doesn't work in general because if one process is in the critical section, the other trying to enter will set the turn variable to itself, perform zero iterations of the busy wait loop (because it's its turn), and also enter the critical section, violating mutual exclusion.